# Testing NSUserDefaults synchronization across app groups in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, xcode8

I have enabled App Groups for my app and its iMessage extension so I can share data between the two. I've implemented NSUserDefaults synchronization in both codebases. However, I haven't found a good way to test synchronization.

In one of the ViewControllers for my main app, I've added this:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.myAppGroup")
                defaults?.setObject(movieTitles, forKey: "movieTitles")
                defaults?.synchronize()
                print("synchronizing movieTitles as \(movieTitles)")
```

In the iMessage extension, I've added this:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.myAppGroup")
    defaults?.synchronize()

    // Check for null value before setting
    if let movieTitles = defaults!.stringForKey("movieTitles") {
        print("synchronized movieTitles from \(movieTitles)")
    }
    else {
        print("Cannot synchronize movieTitles")
    }
```

When I run the app in Simulator, I can see in the console that the sync is happening. When I run the extension in Simulator, I can see in the console that it's attempting to sync (and failing, because the app isn't running so there's nothing to sync). Whenever I try to run both targets at the same time in Simulator, I get this crash for the iMessage extension:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
    0x109d2b380 <+0>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x109d2b383 <+3>:  movl   $0x100001f, %eax          ; imm = 0x100001F 
    0x109d2b388 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x109d2b38a <+10>: retq   
    0x109d2b38b <+11>: nop
```

I'm not proficient enough at debugging to know what that means. The console shows `(lldb)` on the last line too.

Any help is appreciated. How else can I test my synchronization code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After considerable trial and error and re-reading other tutorials, I got it. This [AppCoda tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/) ended up being the last thing I read before I got it working.

In my main app I declared a global variable:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.myOrg.myApp")
```

Then, in a function (of the main app) where the value I want to share gets updated, I used:

```
defaults?.setObject(movieTitles, forKey: "movieTitles")
defaults?.synchronize()
```

From the extension view controller I again declared the global defaults variable and used this in viewDidLoad():

```
if let extMovies = defaults.stringArrayForKey("extensionMovies") {
    print("extMovies is \(extMovies)")
} else {
    print("no extMovies to be found here")
}
```

To test, I ran the app extension first, then the main app. Switching back to the extension in Simulator would sometimes cause a crash, but if I re-ran that schema, I would see my shared variable print to the console.